# put a custom view inside listview

Tags: android, listview, custom-view, android-custom-view

What I need is to put a custom view inside listview's each row, those custom views won't be the same, they will dynamically will be created upon the data. I'm now creating my views but I'm not sure if I can put them inside the listrow. Can I do something like that, myListView.addViewAsRow()?

Thanks

Comment: Hey have a look at Jeff Sharkey's Code Here.. http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Comment: Thanks Kartik but I'm not sure if I can put a custom view with this solution. for example can I say createObject( MyCustomView)?

Comment: I think this link is a little dated now, he should really be making use of convertView when overriding getView, have a look at http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can deduct from your data which rowview to use, you can create a custom adapter and inflate the right one for each row by overriding getView().

There are plenty of examples on overriding getView; this is a good starting point which can also be found on the android developers page (Google I/O 2010, The world of ListView): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70